# Angular router - Navigate back, and my component wont reset from 0. So works wrongly

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic-angular app, and building a Register functionality, where the user goes step by step entering the data that I ask them for.

The user can go backwards (I configured a back arrow button, where if clicked they go back to the route of the previous step), but when doing this, this "previous step" component I just opened won't work as expected.
It looks the same, but some of the data I declare in the properties of the ts file are lost for some reason, so functionality does not work well.

I think it is a lifecycle issue of the component, because it maybe does not reset at all due to it beeing the last component that was openened. ( Just guessing )

I leave the function assigned to the back button when clicked:

```
goBackInNavegation() {
this.router.navigate(['../step2'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, state: {activity: this.activity}});  }
```

Ignore the state object I pass with the "activity".

How do I reset that component I navigate to if the previous navigation was from that previous step (the component im navigating to in the function) to the actual step Im in?

I appreciate any help. Ty :)

Comment: When you route back this way it's like navigating to a new page, isn't it? Why nog use  ``` location.back()``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing the component inside `ngOnInit()` ?

When you go back that function won't be called.
If you want to init data every time you go in, you have to do inside `ionViewWillEnter`

[check this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)